# Query many-to-many in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models. A user has many roles, and a role can have many permissions. I can't quite figure out how to query to get what I want.

```
user_role = db.Table(
    'user_role',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id')),
    db.UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'role_id')
)

role_permission = db.Table(
    'role_permission', 
    db.Column('permission_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('permission.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id')),
    db.UniqueConstraint('permission_id', 'role_id')
)

class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

class Permission(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'permission'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    roles = db.relation(Role, secondary=role_permission, backref=db.backref('permissions'))

class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    roles = db.relation(Role, secondary=user_role, backref=db.backref('users'))
```

I want to get a (preferably unique) list of all the permissions assigned to a user, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I can get the list by creating a generator in the User model:

```
def get_all_permissions(self):
    for role in self.roles:
        for perm in role.permissions:
            yield perm
```

But I'd love to be able to do it in one query.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to just get a list of the permissions, try something like this:

```
permissions = session.query(Permission).\
    join(Role).join(User).filter(User.username='MisterX').all()
```

Or filter for whatever you want. To make the Permissions unique, you could use group by:

```
permissions = session.query(Permission.id, Permission.name).join(Role).join(User).\
    filter(User.username='MisterX').group_by(Permission.id).all()
```

Or, without a special query, use the declarative extension, if you can:

```
permissions = User.roles.permissions
```

Does that help?

Comment: This does not seem to work at all. Trying session.query(Permission).join(Role) gives me "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <class 'models.auth.Role'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'permission' and 'role'." When I try "User.roles.permissions" I get "AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.roles has an attribute 'permissions'"

Comment: Print the resulting query like this: `print(session.query(Permission).join(Role).join(User).filter(User.username='MisterX'))` and then see if it runs in the normal mysql shell. You can also check whether SQLAlchemy got your relations right this way. Be sure to replace the placeholders with actual values!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your association tables are not recognized properly, as you did not specify the metadata parameter. This script works for me:

```
#!/bin/python

from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine, Column, PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

user_role = Table(
    'user_role',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
    Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id')),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'role_id')
)

role_permission = Table(
    'role_permission', 
    Base.metadata,
    Column('permission_id', Integer, ForeignKey('permissions.id')),
    Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id')),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('permission_id', 'role_id')
)

class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

class Permission(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'permissions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    roles = relationship("Role", secondary=role_permission, backref=backref('permissions'))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = Column(String(80), nullable=False)

    roles = relationship("Role", secondary=user_role, backref=backref('users'))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

u = User(username="user", password_hash="secret")

r1 = Role(name="Role 1")
session.add(r1)
r2 = Role(name="Role 2")
session.add(r2)

p1 = Permission(name="Permission 1")
p2 = Permission(name="Permission 2")
p3 = Permission(name="Permission 3")

r1.permissions.append(p1)
r1.permissions.append(p2)

r2.permissions.append(p2)
r2.permissions.append(p3)


u.roles.append(r1)
u.roles.append(r2)

session.add(u)

for perm in session.query(Permission).join(Role, Permission.roles).\
    join(User, Role.users).filter(User.username=="user").distict()all():
    print(perm.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have loaded User object already into memory together with Permissions and Roles, you code should do it quickly and without going to a database.

Otherwise, this query should work:

```
    user_id = 789
    permissions = (db.session.query(Permission)
            .join(Role, Permission.roles)
            .join(User, Role.users)
            .filter(User.id == user_id)
            ).distinct()
    #print(permissions)
    for perm in permissions:
        print(perm)
```