# Flask-SQLAlchemy many to many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Coming from Django, I am having a hard time figuring out just how the many to many relationship works.

The following models.py does not work, I get the error: *InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Error creating backref 'sectors' on relationship 'Sector.companies': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Company|companies'*

The code is the following:

```
`    
company_contacts = db.Table('company_contacts',
                       db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id')),
                       db.Column('contact_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contacts.id'))
                       )


company_sectors = db.Table('company_sectors',
                   db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id')),
                   db.Column('sector_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sectors.id'))
                   )

company_worklists = db.Table('company_worklists',
                   db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id')),
                   db.Column('worklist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('worklists.id'))
                   )


class Sector(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'sectors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name_srb= db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    name_ita= db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)

    companies = db.relationship('Company',
                           secondary = company_sectors,
                           backref = db.backref('sectors', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')



class Contact(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'contacts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False)
    position_srb = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False)
    position_ita = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)

    #companies = db.relationship('Company',
                           #secondary = company_contacts,
                           #backref = db.backref('companies', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           #lazy = 'dynamic')



class WorkList(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'worklists'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default = datetime.now)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)
    slug =  db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True)


class Company(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = False)
    website = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = False)
    desc = db.Column(db.Text())
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)
    slug =  db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    fax = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = False)



    contacts = db.relationship('Contact',
                           secondary = company_contacts,
                           backref = db.backref('contacts', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')

    sectors = db.relationship('Sector',
                           secondary = company_sectors,
                           backref = db.backref('sectors', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')


    wlists= db.relationship('WorkList',
                           secondary = company_worklists,
                           backref = db.backref('wlists', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')
```

I want to be able to access things like Company.contacts and Contact.companies...
    `'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [`relationship(backref=...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.backref) construction is a convenience mechainism so that you can get references pointing in both directions, a `Company.sectors` and a `Sector.companies` having defined only one.  You have defined both relationships.  You seem to have already figured this out; your code includes many would be duplicate references in commented-out form.

Remove all of the duplicate relationships (where you have defined a corresponding backref) and you should be fine.

Alternatively, you can use the [`relationship(back_populates=...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) construct and define all of the realtionships explicitly.  that way, you can see on each class what sort of collection attributes it has on the class itself, but they will be tied together properly.

Comment: Yes, ifLoop, thank you, the duplicates got me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of IfLoop is correct, but you also should include the metadata parameter to the definitions of the association tables. I modified your example to make it run:

```
#!/bin/python

from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Text, String, ForeignKey, create_engine, Column, PrimaryKeyConstraint, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

company_contacts = Table('company_contacts', Base.metadata, Column('company_id', Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id')), Column('contact_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contacts.id')) )

company_sectors = Table('company_sectors',
                    Base.metadata,
                    Column('company_id', Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id')),
                    Column('sector_id', Integer, ForeignKey('sectors.id'))
                   )

company_worklists = Table('company_worklists',
                    Base.metadata,
                   Column('company_id', Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id')),
                   Column('worklist_id', Integer, ForeignKey('worklists.id'))
                   )


class Sector(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'sectors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name_srb= Column(String(64), unique = True)
    name_ita= Column(String(64), unique = True)



class Contact(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contacts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique = False)
    last_name = Column(String(64), unique = False)
    position_srb = Column(String(64), unique = False)
    position_ita = Column(String(64), unique = False)
    email = Column(String(120), unique = True)
    phone = Column(String(100))
    created = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)

    #companies = relationship('Company',
                           #secondary = company_contacts,
                           #backref = backref('companies', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           #lazy = 'dynamic')



class WorkList(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'worklists'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = Column(String(64), unique = True)
    created = Column(DateTime(), default = datetime.now)
    updated = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)
    slug =  Column(String(100), unique = True)


class Company(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique = True)
    address = Column(String(120), unique = False)
    website = Column(String(100), unique = False)
    city = Column(String(20), unique = False)
    desc = Column(Text())
    email = Column(String(120), unique = True)
    created = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now,onupdate=datetime.now)
    slug =  Column(String(100), unique = True)
    phone = Column(String(100))
    fax = Column(String(100), unique = False)



    contacts = relationship('Contact',
                           secondary = company_contacts,
                           backref = backref('contacts', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')

    sectors = relationship('Sector',
                           secondary = company_sectors,
                           backref = backref('companies', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')


    wlists= relationship('WorkList',
                           secondary = company_worklists,
                           backref = backref('wlists', lazy = 'dynamic'),
                           lazy = 'dynamic')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

company = Company(name="C1")
session.add(company)

contact = Contact(last_name="Doe", name="John")

company.contacts.append(contact)
```

May I ask where you got the "db." convention from? There is another recent question where the metadata parameter was also missing: [Query many-to-many in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392770/query-many-to-many-in-sqlalchemy/)

Comment: It is from Flask-SQLAlchemy. Thank you.

Comment: Cool answer. I'm just wondering whether the table company_contacts can be created implicitly. I mean we understand one company can have multiple contracts, if it can have some syntax like django to define `OneToMany()` directly.